# Paypal NVP APIs - How to initiate a Bill Payment?

Tags: paypal, recurring

I want to initiate a bill payment with variable amount through API.

PayPal shows details on following link how to initiate through interface but I couldn't find relevant API to trigger it programmatically.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/manage-billing-plans/

Could you please give me reference or code sample to trigger Bill now with variable amount.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be able to bill at arbitrary times for a variable amount you need the Business account to be approved for "Reference Transactions", so you can set up a billing agreement checkout and reference that agreement ID in the future.

The owner of the business account should contact PayPal's general business support to request this feature, via https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us

If the account is approved for the feature, PayPal's support can give you guidance on which API or newer Vault integration to use.